# How do you find all macro calls in an elisp file?

Tags: elisp-macros, byte-compilation

I am trying to make sure a package that is installed from Melpa (`org-ref`) byte compiles correctly, and a typical issue is related to the use of macros. For example, if I use `org-with-wide-buffer` which is a macro defined in `org-macs.el` I need to make sure to put

`(eval-and-compile (require 'org-macs))` in it so the package works as expected from Melpa.

The tricky thing is finding all the macro calls, so I know when to do this. I wondered if there is a way to find these in an elisp file. It seems like one just walks through all the s-exps and checks if the `(macrop (car sexp))` is non-nil, and print it or something so I can figure out what to put at the top. Does something like this already exist?

Or is there some way to test if there are uncompiled macro calls? I already can cleanly compile the package; the issues come up when using the functions.

Comment: Your need might be to also have the macros defined at runtime, in which case `eval-and-compile` is appropriate. But your question (a very good one) is otherwise more general, and in the more typical case `eval-when-compile` is called for (the macros are needed only at compile time). If you agree, you might consider either mentioning this or in some other way generalizing your question. We don't have a lot of good questions about Elisp macros here...

Comment: I have a lot of related questions on this topic, like how to tell when you need eval-and-compile vs eval-when-compile. Do you think that could go here, or should be a separate question?

Comment: A separate question, I think. Specific or narrow questions are generally more helpful and get better answers, I think.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do it interactively with `el-search` (http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/el-search.html).

```
M-x el-search `(,(pred macrop) ,_)
```

finds them. Interestingly, it matches backticked s-exps like  `` `(:annotation-function ,type-annotation) `` too.

Here is an interactive function version:

```
(defun find-macro-calls-1 ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (el-search (read "`(,(pred macrop) ,_)")))
```

Comment: `el-search.el` is Michael Heerdegen's library; it's not part of vanilla Emacs (yet), right? If so, please consider adding a link to the library or info about it. Thx.